# Representing Typed N-tuples in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, coding-style

```
List<struct {string, string, double} > L = new List<struct {string, string, double}>;
L.Add({"hi", "mom", 5.0});
```

What is the nicest way to get this functionality in C#? I want to define a strongly-typed tuple on the fly (for use in a local function), save a bunch of them in a list, do some processing and return a result, never to touch the list again.

I don't actually care about the strong typing, but a List of vars doesn't work. Do I want a list of objects? Is that the closest I can get?

Defining structs or classes for temporary data structures seems verbose and pedantic to me.

Comment: Too much Lua programming may have ruined me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to represent this in C# is to use the `Tuple` type

```
var l = new List<Tuple<string, string, double>>();
l.Add(Tuple.Create("hi", "mom", 42.0));
```

There's no explicit language support for tuples but as you can see the API isn't *too* wordy

Comment: You could also write an extension method to make a little less wordy. Then you could do something like l.Add(1,2,3);

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr = new[] { Tuple.Create("hi","mom", 5.0) };
```

is the easiest; this is actually an array, but a list is easy enough too  - perhaps `.ToList()` if you feel lazy.

Personally, in this scenario I'd use an anon-type:

```
var arr = new[] { new { Text = "hi", Name = "mom", Value = 5.0 } };
```

Very similar, except the member-names are more meaningful.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer anonymous types here too.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at [using anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx?ppud=4) as an alternative to Tuples.

Example initialization of array of anon types and looping over the result:

```
var anons = new [] { new {num=1, str="str1"},
                     new {num=2, str="str2"} };

foreach(var v in anons) Console.WriteLine(v.num + " " + v.str);
```

Comment: The problem is that it's very hard to declare a `List<T>` when `T` is an anonymous type.

Comment: If you're only using it in the context of a single method, you don't need to specify `T`.  You could use a combination of `var` inference, linq `.ToList()`, and anonymous classes to manage it.

Comment: @Gabe: I know the OP mentioned a list but I don't know that a List<T> is necessary. Please see the code snippet I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Tuple<string, string, double>> L = new List<Tuple<string, string, double>>();
L.Add(Tuple.Create("hi", "mom", 5.0));
```

More on the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 4.0, you can use the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) type

Comment: Note that it is immutable, and also gives you a slightly odd looking .Item1, .Item2 etc properties to access each tuple component value

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class, introduced in .NET 4.0?

Another option is to use [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of would be to use Tuples:

```
        var L = new List<Tuple<string, string, double>>();

        L.Add(Tuple.Create("a", "b", 10D));
```

Alternatively you could also use a list of dynamics

Comment: `ExpandoObject` might just be the dynamic type to use.